# Position \tikz\node on running text flow, aligned at baseline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

In the MWE below, I'd like the inserted "y" nodes to be aligned at baseline, so there is no difference from flow of running text; then finally, I want to align the "X" node with one of the "y" nodes, again at baseline. However, instead I get this:

[image: test.png]

How could I achieve that the "y" nodes are aligned the same as in the word "yesty" (and the "X" node aligned at such "y" node at baseline, without interfering the flow of text)?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzstyle{rpo} = [remember picture,overlay]
\tikzstyle{nn} = [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=0pt,anchor=base]
\tikzstyle{nf} = [nn,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{nr} = [nn,draw=red]
\def\tzn{\tikz\node}
\def\tzrn{\tikz[remember picture]\node}
\def\tzon{\tikz[rpo]\node}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Testy yesty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  Testy  yesty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy

\noindent
Testy \tzn[nn]{y};esty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  Testy  \tzn[nf]{y};esty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy

\noindent
Testy yesty testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  Testy  \tzrn[nf,baseline=(A.base)](A){y};esty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy

\tzon[nr,draw=red,anchor=base] at (A.base) {X};

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ah, got it; see, I had:

```
\tzrn[nf,baseline=(A.base)](A){y}
```

... which expands to:

```
\tikz[remember picture]\node[nf,baseline=(A.base)](A){y}
```

... however, that is wrong, the `baseline` parameter should be applied to `\tikz` - not to `\node` (there was a post about this on this site, but I lost the link). The correct would be:

```
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(A.base)]\node[nf](A){y}
```

... or `baseline=0pt` and `baseline=(current bounding box.base)` also seem to work. So the outcome now - minding also the correct `remember picture` (node flowing in with text should have only this) and `overlay` (node being overlaid should have both) - is this:

[image: /test.png]

... using this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzstyle{rpo} = [remember picture,overlay]
\tikzstyle{nn} = [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=0pt,anchor=base]
\tikzstyle{nf} = [nn,draw=black]
\tikzstyle{nr} = [nn,draw=red]
\def\tzn{\tikz\node}
\def\tzrn{\tikz[remember picture]\node}
\def\tzRn{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(current bounding box.base)]\node}
\def\tzon{\tikz[rpo]\node}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Testy yesty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  Testy  yesty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy

\noindent
Testy \tzn[nn]{y};esty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  Testy  \tzRn[nf]{y};esty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy

\noindent
Testy yesty testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  Testy  \tzRn[nf](A){y};esty  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy  testy

\tzon[nr,draw=red,anchor=base] at (A.base) {X};

\end{document}
```